# Eigenvalues of a Product of two matrices A and B inside trace operator expressed in terms of any eigenvalue of A or B?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This question has been in asked in a few varieties here but not in this one.

If we have a real, symmetric, positive-definite matrix $A$ and a real, symmetric, positive-definite matrix $B$ and we know an eigenvalue of each of them say, $l$ and $k$ respectively, can we express the eigenvalues of the product $AB$ in terms of $l$ and $k$?

Moreover, through some helpful comments, I have learned that they need to be simultaneously diagonalizable. So suppose they're inside the trace, so $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$, does that admit an expression that involves only the eigenvalue of one of them?

Thank you so much!

Comment: So you're expecting that knowing one eigenvalue of each matrix will completely determine the eigenvalues of the product?

Comment: Thanks @GitGud No I am expecting that the eigenvalues of the product may be the product of the eigenvalues or something similar? I have tried writing it out but I don't know enough matrix theory. Thank you!

Comment: They are not unless $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: @Hirek Then perhaps you want to write "can we express *an* eigenvalue (...)" instead of "can we express the eigenvalues (...)".

Comment: Ah thank you so much! @AlgebraicPavel Suppose we have the matrices inside the trace so tr(AB) and knowing that the tr is the sum of the eigenvalues of the product, is there a way to write tr(AB) via the eigenvalues of B and A individually?

Comment: Even if $A$ and $B$ were simultanously diagonalizable, it would not be so easy if you did not know a priori which eigenvalues correspond to which eigenvectors. If what you asked was true, then $\mathrm{tr}(AB)$ would remain constant no matter what orthogonal similarity transformations you would do independently to $A$ and $B$. Simple $2\times 2$ examples can confirm that.

Comment: Hmm ok @AlgebraicPavel but the trace is the sum of all eigenvalues, right? Shouldn't there be some ordering in magnitude that allows 'matching' them for each summand?

Comment: @Hirek What is true is that the eigenvalues of $A \otimes B$ are the products of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$, counting multiplicity.

Comment: @Hirem We cannot determine the trace of a product from the traces of the factors. Consider $D := \text{diag}(1, -1)$. Then $(\text{tr } D)(\text{tr } D) = 0$ but $\text{tr } (D^2) = 2$. On the other hand, for the zero matrix $\bf 0$, $(\text{tr } {\bf 0})(\text{tr } {\bf 0}) = 0$ and $\text{tr }({\bf 0}^2) = 0$.

Comment: @Hirek Yes, there would be *some* ordering: given by the eigenvectors.

Comment: We can at least put a bound on the eigenvalues of a product of $AB$. If the largest eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ have respective magnitudes $\Lambda$ and $\text{M}$, then for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have $|Ax| \leq \Lambda |x|$, $|Bx| \leq \text{M} |y|$, and so for all $x$ we have $|ABx| \leq \Lambda |Bx| \leq \Lambda \text{M} |x|$. Hence, the largest eigenvalue of $AB$ can be no larger than $\Lambda \text{M}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Lambda_A$ and $\Lambda_B$ be the spectra of $A$ and $B$, respectively. If $\mathrm{tr}(AB)$ was dependent only on the spectra of $A$ and $B$, that is,
$$
\mathrm{tr}(AB)=f(\Lambda_A,\Lambda_B),
$$
then for any orthogonal matrices $U$ and $V$, $\tilde{A}:=U^TAU$ and $\tilde{B}:=V^TBV$ would be still SPD with the spectra $\Lambda_A$ and $\Lambda_B$ and $\mathrm{tr}(\tilde{A}\tilde{B})=f(\Lambda_A,\Lambda_B)=\mathrm{tr}(AB)$. This is simply not true.

Consider
$$
A:=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}, \quad B:=\pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}, \quad \mathrm{tr}(AB)=4.
$$
Let
$$
U:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&1\\-1&1}, \quad V:=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}
$$
be two orthogonal matrices and set
$$
\tilde{A}=U^TAU=\frac{1}{2}\pmatrix{3&-1\\-1&3},\quad
\tilde{B}=V^TBV=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}.
$$
Clearly, $\mathrm{tr}(\tilde{A}\tilde{B})=\frac{9}{2}\neq 4=\mathrm{tr}(AB)$, even though both $A$ and $\tilde{A}$ (and $B$ and $\tilde{B}$) have the same eigenvalues. Consequently, $\mathrm{tr}(AB)$ is not a function depending only on the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thank you so much @Algebraic Pavel. This helps tremendously and I learned a great deal although I wish the answer had been the opposite. The reason I am asking this is that I am integrating over a product of a view matrix operations and wish to simplify my integrand. This however is hard because the trace of the product is in the way. I will try it with the vectorization operator though.